# How can I fill icon color after onclick function using jquery in react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Here is my code.Let me advice ,I want to change icon color after onclick function .

```
<div class="timeline-footer">
  <a
    id="changeicon"
    onClick={(event) => this.handleCount(post.id, event)}
    class="m-r-25"
  ><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> {post.rating} Like</a>
</div>
```

This is my rating count function

```
handleCount(id, event) {
  event.classList.toggle("icon-heart");

  fetch(this.state.url + '/rating/' + id, {
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
      'Accept': 'applicatoin/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    window.location.reload();
  })
}
```

Comment: This seems rather easy. You could make the class a state property and change the state at the end of your onClick function.

Comment: btw, in react, use `className` instead of `class` [DOM Elements in ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to change color after each click?
You can do it more 'react-way' without using jquery through state changing:

```
changeColor = (color) => this.setState({iconColor: color});

getIconStyle = () => ({
    color: this.state.iconColor
});

handleCount = (id, event) => {
    event.classList.toggle("icon-heart");

    this.changeColor("red"); // or anyway you want

    fetch(this.state.url + '/rating/' + id, {
        method: 'POST',
        header: {
            'Accept': 'applicatoin/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        window.location.reload();
    })
}
```

Inside render:

```
<div className="timeline-footer">
     <a 
         id="changeicon" 
         onClick={(event) => this.handleCount(post.id, event)}
         style={this.getIconStyle()}
         className="m-r-25"
     >
          <i className="fa fa-heart-o"></i> {post.rating} Like
     </a>
</div>
```

Or change class instead of style if it suits your case

Comment: That's ok. but my post are dynamic data.So icon in every post are  changed to red .How can I fix that

Comment: @GuGue then you should change `this.changeColor("red")` to smth like `this.changeColor(this.getColor(some_args))`